# Table numbering in unnumbered chapters (e.g. \chapter*)

Tags: tables, numbering, chapters

I've tried to google this in about a dozen different ways, but didn't find anything.

I have an introduction chapter that uses \chapter*. The numbering of the subsections is fine - they're still numbered as 0.X, which is exactly what I want. However, tables and figures are numbered without an initial 0.X, so I simply get Table 1, etc. I would like the Tables to be numbered starting with "Table 0.1" in the introduction.

I also have an appendix which is also produced unnumbered (or lettered). The code from the (dissertation) style file I'm using is shown below. I would like here to have the Tables labelled A.1 or A.2. Currently I get "Table .1" and "Table .2" instead.

```
\newcount\chap@or@app\chap@or@app=1

\def\appendixname{Appendix}

\def\appendix{\clearpage
    \typeout{Appendix.}
    \short@page                 % <- 9/13/96 (MAL)
        \markboth{}{}\pagestyle{myheadings} % <- The appendix must 
        \thispagestyle{plain}           % <- be numbered.
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \centerline{\large\bf Appendix}
    \vspace*{\fill}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}  % <-

    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \def\@chapapp{\appendixname}
    \chap@or@app=2
   %\def\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}} % Commented out 15 Aug 02   cwm
                    % as a partial solution to
                    % the problem of labeling
                    % one appendix as Appendix A.
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `chngcntr` package, you can write

```
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}
```

to get your tables, for example, to be numbered with chapter numbers.

If you don't want to call yet another package, then you can accomplish this also as

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{table}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\makeatother
```

As for the appendix, you should be able to do something like

```
\renewcommand\thetable{A.\arabic{table}}
```

And similarly for your figures.